# How do I change the default font of Evernote?

Tags: default-settings, evernote

Just as the title says, how do I change the default font of `Evernote` so that whenever I `create a new note` the default font will not be `Tahoma 10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, just do the following

1. Click the **`tools`**
2. Then click the **`Options`** `(A pop up window will show up)`
3. Click the **`Note`** and there you are.

You can now change the default font. After saving, please restart the Evernote for it to take effect.